# trouble deleting an object by id from a nested array in Mongoose with $pull

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am having trouble deleting a Card object that is nested in a Cards array thats inside of a Deck object.

[image: deck schema]

[image: deleteCardController & Deck]

I've tried using the deck.updateOne and $pull to no avail. I also tried removing the quotation marks from the keys. What am I missing here?

(I'm using Mongoose ^7.0.3)

Thanks in advance!

Deck object:

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("646a4b13376b75ce9833e156"),
  title: 'Week 5',
  cards: [
    {
      text: '5.1f',
      definition: '5.1b',
      _id: new ObjectId("646a4b19376b75ce9833e15b")
    },
    {
      text: '5.2f',
      definition: '5.2b',
      _id: new ObjectId("646a4b1d376b75ce9833e15f")
    },
    {
      text: '5.3f',
      definition: '5.3b',
      _id: new ObjectId("646a4b22376b75ce9833e164")
    },
    {
      text: '5.4f ',
      definition: '5.4b',
      _id: new ObjectId("646a5f70c9a7ffe0dfbc6e83")
    },
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("646a6c6c6f0e89ea73658cf7"),
      text: '5.4f',
      definition: '5.4b'
    },
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("646a6c6c6f0e89ea73658cf8"),
      text: '5.5f',
      definition: '5.5b'
    },
    {
      text: '5.6f',
      definition: '5.6b',
      _id: new ObjectId("646a68853ab047db4e998db2")
    },
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("646a6c6c6f0e89ea73658cfa"),
      text: '5.7f',
      definition: '5.7b'
    },
    {
      text: '5.8f',
      definition: '5.8b',
      _id: new ObjectId("646a6c1308b4c3e8ec555184")
    },
    {
      text: '5.9f',
      definition: '5.9b',
      _id: new ObjectId("646a6c5f6f0e89ea73658cc0")
    }
  ],
  __v: 21
}
```

Deck model:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const DeckSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  cards: [{text: String, definition: String }],
});


const DeckModel = mongoose.model('Deck', DeckSchema);

export default DeckModel;
```

deleteCardController:

```
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import Deck from "../models/Deck";
import mongoose from "mongoose"

export async function deleteCardController(req: Request,res: Response){
    const deckId = req.params.deckId;
    const cardId = req.params.cardId;

    const deck = await Deck.findById(deckId);

    if(!deck) return res.status(400).send("deck Id does not exist");
    deck.updateOne({_id: deckId}, {$pull: {cards: {_id: cardId}}})

    

    await deck.save();
    

    res.json(deck);

}
```

}

Comment: Please don't remove the code from your question. The image is not a good replacement for it. It needs to be posted as text. (Rolled back your edit).

Comment: If you remove `await deck.save();`, does the collection document have the desired content?  I'm wondering if `updateOne` succeeds, and then `save` restores it to its previous content.

Comment: I commented out deck.save() and nothing changes. It appears that deck.updateOne isn't working as intended but I'm not quite sure why.

Comment: I'm not a _mongooser_, but perhaps `mongoose` isn't _auto-casting_ `cardId`. If you explicitly convert `cardId` to an `ObjectId`, does it work then?

Comment: `cards` doesn't have an `_id` in your schema? Also please do replace the images with text of the code and data. The result of the commands (response from the database) would also help troubleshoot

Comment: I tried casting the deckId and cardId to a new mongoose.Types.ObjectId on const assignment, but it didn't work.

const deckId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.deckId);
const cardId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.cardId);

Comment: When I explicitly put _id:String in the card object in the cards array in DeckSchema, it no longer assigns an _id to the card. Admittedly I don't Mongoose well enough to know why, so I didn't include it. Should I include?

Comment: Again, I'm not a _mongooser_, but should it be `Deck.updateOne(...` rather than `deck.updateOne(...` (note the capitalization)?

Comment: @rickhg12hs I tried doing it with both: Deck.updateOne({_id: deckId},{$pull: {'cards': {_id: cardId}}}) and const deck = await Deck.findById(deckId); deck.updateOne({$pull: {'cards': {_id: cardId}}}) but to no avail

Comment: I suspect this is a `mongoose` related issue. A _bare_ MongoDB update works as seen in this [mongoplayground.net example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bCGg2QZ45N5).